# Synchronized appending to file with java using OS synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization

i got two java processes running on the same machine in parallel, i want these processes to append debugging data to the same file when the order at which they append is crucial and must be preserved. because these two processes share nothing but the OS itself, i think i need OS IO synchronization.

so how is it done on java?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately java 7 provides file lock. Take a look on this discussion: http://www.adme.ru/vdohnovenie-919705/samyj-sumasshedshij-tryuk-531205/

and javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html